# Are the similarities between Homura Akemi and Kiritsugu Emiya intentional?

Tags: madoka-magica, fate-zero

Puella Magi Madoka Magica's Homura Akemi and Fate/Zero's Kiritsugu Emiya were both written by Gen Urobuchi, although Kiritsugu was created by Type Moon's Kinoko Nasu. There are numerous similarities between them:

- Both are magic users with control over time.
- Both augment their magical powers with modern weaponry.
- Both are very taciturn, but deeply loving towards certain people (Homura towards Madoka and Kiritsugu towards Iri and Illya).
- Both are mentally damaged by the horrors of war (Homura's experiences in the time loops and Kiritsugu's experiences in various war zones over the years).
- Both characters are pivotal to the events of the story, but for most of the series the viewers, and even the main heroine herself, have no idea what they are thinking.
- Both have something of a gap in ideals with the main heroine (Homura's actions during the movie go against Madoka's wishes, while Kiritsugu and Saber clash so much from the very beginning that Kiritsugu assigns her to work with Iri).
- Both have great hair :)

[image: Kiritsugu]
[image: Homura]

Was this just an archetype of Urobuchi's writing, the way Stephen King spent three decades writing about common household objects trying to kill people? Or is there an interview or any evidence which suggests this was intentional? As a related question, how much of Kiritsugu's overlap with Homura was Nasu's doing, and how much was Urobuchi's?

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but Urobuchi's afterword to the first volume of Fate/Zero basically presages Madoka. Worth having a look at, imo. (P.S. Kiritsugu's hair is nowhere near Homura-tier. ill fite u irl m8.)

Comment: @senshin That afterword was very interesting, and Nasu's portion suggests that Urobuchi did almost all of the writing for Kiritsugu, which answers my related question. Also, though I consider Kiritsugu's hair pretty great, I recognize that Kiritsugu would have to have Super Saiyan 3-level hair to approach the magnificence of Homu Homu's lissome tresses.

Comment: @Torisuda unrelated to the question but do you have a bigger version of that image of Homura hold that dead Incubator?

Comment: @Memor-X http://www.zerochan.net/930196#full to get the full-size of that image.

Comment: My own inclination is that this is simply a case of recycling tropes and themes by the author; a lot of themes from Fate/Zero ended up (differently developed) in PMMM

Comment: @MeirIllumination That was my default hypothesis too, but since Urobuchi (unlike many anime creators) has a lot of interviews floating around out there, I figured I would ask and see if anyone knew of one where he talks about this.